# Displaying audio data in HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, audio, visualization

so I have the following javascript code which makes a sound visualiser that works on chrome with microphone input. Although, the actual visualiser works well, I was wondering if I could actually get the audio data from the uint8array called array and display it in a paragraph with id = "arrayIndex". However, when I try to display array[i], it always comes out as zero and doesn't change with the visualizer. Does anyone have any idea how I can capture the values in the array? Thanks!

```
    addEventListener('load', init);
    function init() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
    window.AudioContext = window.ctx = document.getElementById('c').getContext('2d');
    gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 200);
    gradient.addColorStop(1, '#ADD8E6');
    gradient.addColorStop(0.65, '#576D74');
    gradient.addColorStop(0.45, '#FFAA00');
    gradient.addColorStop(0, '#FF0000');
    ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
    window.AudioContext = window.webkitAudioContext || window.AudioContext;
    context = new AudioContext();
    analyser = context.createAnalyser();
    analyser.fftsize = 512;
    analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = 0.9;
    navigator.getMedia = (navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia);
    navigator.getMedia({
        audio: true,
        video: false
    }, function (localMediaStream) {
        source = context.createMediaStreamSource(localMediaStream);
        console.log(source);
        source.connect(analyser);
        draw();
    }, function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
function draw() {
    var array = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
    analyser.getByteFrequencyData(array);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 512, 256);
    var barHeight;

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    barHeight = 256-array[i];
    ctx.fillRect(i * 2, barHeight, 1, 256);
    document.getElementById("arrayIndex").innerHTML = barHeight;
}



requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

}

Comment: I tried your code (or a variant of it) and it worked. Perhaps you have a typo in "arrayIndex". Try adding a console.log(barHeight) to confirm that you are getting the values.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response! You mean you got the barHeight variable to display on the page and constantly change? My console.log(barHeight) gives me the values but it only displays zero in the paragraph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right!

There is some quirk in both Chrome and Firefox. If you fix the frequency index to e.g. 50 it works. It is a bad idea to be updating the html at such a high rate (i.e. over 15kHz in this case). This quirk might be due to the ridiculous update rate. Also, it will work if you take the update out of the loop.

Here is a working
[fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/traustikristjansson/gup34sfh/24/) Notice the text below the spectrogram updates correctly.

Here is the code from the fiddle:

```
var canvasCtx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
var bufferSize = 4096;
var audioContext;

try {
    window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
    audioContext = new AudioContext();
} catch (e) {
    alert('Web Audio API is not supported in this browser');
}

// Check if there is microphone input.
try {
    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||     navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;
    var hasMicrophoneInput = (navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia);
} catch (e) {
    alert("getUserMedia() is not supported in your browser");
}

// Create analyser node.
var analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser();

analyser.fftsize = 512;
analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = 0.9;
var bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount;
var dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);

var errorCallback = function (e) {
    alert("Error in getUserMedia: " + e);
};

// Get access to the microphone and start pumping data through the  graph.
navigator.getUserMedia({
    audio: true
}, function (stream) {
    // microphone -&gt; myPCMProcessingNode -&gt; destination.
    var microphone = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    microphone.connect(analyser);
    analyser.connect(audioContext.destination);
    //microphone.start(0);
}, errorCallback);

// draw an oscilloscope of the current audio source

function draw() {

    drawVisual = requestAnimationFrame(draw);

    analyser.getByteFrequencyData(dataArray);

    canvasCtx.fillStyle = 'rgb(200, 200, 200)';
    var WIDTH = 500;
    var HEIGHT = 256;
    canvasCtx.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    for (var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
      barHeight = HEIGHT - dataArray[i];
      canvasCtx.fillRect(i * 2, barHeight, 1, dataArray[i]);
      // It is a bad idea to update an element in this loop:
      // However, if you do, the following line always gives 0, which seems like a bug.
      document.getElementById("arrayIndex").innerHTML = dataArray[i];
      // This line works though.
      document.getElementById("arrayIndex").innerHTML = dataArray[50];
    }
};

draw();
```

Here is more background on the WebAPI for [real time audio processing:](http://papers.traustikristjansson.info/?p=486).

Comment: Thanks so much for the clear code and suggestions. I figured that the problem was the rapid update rate and 0 was the most common value so I guess it was just spamming 0's really quickly. Finding a sweet spot in the array is the best solution so far. Thanks for finding it!